# Howto get Image selector who opens with onClick to select one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new here and new with Javascript. I have medium experience with HTML and CSS.
I hope that someone can help me with a solution for my question:

I have a HTML table with an Image in a cell. I defined for the cell 20 different Images: the standard background Image is the (first) one with a Question mark.

When clicking the '?' Image the next image appears in the cell. On clicking it again, then the next appears, etc. etc. until the '?' appears again.  To go to the 20th Image, the user has to click 20 times. The same happens when a user clicks too fast and the Image he/she wants disappeared. That's user unfriendly.

Is it possible (only when a user CLICKS ON the '?-IMAGE') to show a floating box who shows all the pre-defined Images for that category? When a user choose one of them with onClick, the '?' Image disappear and the cell displays the selected one and the floating screen must close automatically. The user can go now to the next Category (or clicks again on the new selected Image to open the box again).

What do I have to define in HTML, CSS and Javascript?

Thank you!

Example (with 5 Images):
https://demo.logisym.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/sample.html

Comment: Read how to improve your question by providing a [mcve].

Comment: yes, it is possible. please, provide your work first (code on html, css and javascript (in sandbox or inline code sample), or add images of how it should look).

Comment: Hi @AlexeyObukhov, thanks for your reply. I added an URL with a sample in the Question above.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the js code as per my understanding on your requirement. All lines are commented.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <!-- <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script> -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .floating-image-wrapper {
            display: none;
            justify-content: start;
            align-items: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .floating-image-wrapper img {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>



    <table>
        <tr>
            <br>
            <th>Your Image:</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><img src="http://demo.logisym.nl/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/05/image-leeg.jpg" data-image-id="0"
                    onClick="imagefun1()" id="getImage1"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="floating-image-wrapper">
        <img src="http://demo.logisym.nl/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/05/loc-img-1.jpg" alt=""
            onClick="imageclick(this, 1)">
        <img src="http://demo.logisym.nl/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/05/loc-img-2.jpg" alt=""
            onClick="imageclick(this, 2)">
        <img src="http://demo.logisym.nl/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/05/loc-img-3.jpg" alt=""
            onClick="imageclick(this, 3)">
        <img src="http://demo.logisym.nl/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/05/loc-img-4.jpg" alt=""
            onClick="imageclick(this, 4)">
        <img src="http://demo.logisym.nl/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/05/loc-img-5.jpg" alt=""
            onClick="imageclick(this, 5)">
    </div>


    <script>
        const Image_Id = document.getElementById('getImage1'); // capture the main image element
        const floatingImageWrapper = document.querySelector(".floating-image-wrapper");

        function imagefun1() { // function executed when main image element is clicked

            const Current_Image_Id = parseInt(Image_Id.getAttribute('data-image-id')); // capture the current image index
           
            floatingImageWrapper.style.display = 'flex'; // used flex design. optional to use column css. depends on the framework used
                
                setTimeout(()=>{ // optional: to hide the floating image wrapper after 3 seconds
                    floatingImageWrapper.style.display = 'none';
                }, 3000);
                
            if (Current_Image_Id === 5) { // if last image is in main image, then load the ? image
                Image_Id.setAttribute('src', 'http://demo.logisym.nl/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/05/image-leeg.jpg');
                Image_Id.setAttribute('data-image-id', 0);
                return;
            }

        }

        function imageclick(ele, index) { // function executed when floating image wrapper image elements clicked
            Image_Id.setAttribute('src', ele.getAttribute('src')); // get the attr src and place it in main image
            Image_Id.setAttribute('data-image-id', index); // updated the image index on main image
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: @Alexey Obukhov, I'm very happy with your solution. This is exactly what I had in mind. Thank you very much for your fast response.

Comment: @Alexey Obukhov, (A) I have a lot a cells in the table. Do I have to duplicate the script for every 'Imagefun<nr>' or is it possible to do that in the script too?  

(B) Is is possible to show the images in not 1-2-3-4-5  but 1, 2 next row 3,4 next row 5. Because with 30 Images they don't fit on the screen in 1 row.

Comment: (A) You need not duplicate. Since you are using wordpress, you could use jquery that will avoid duplication of codes in a better way.

Comment: (B). That's why flex design is used, you could see a class flex-wrap, it will wrapup the images. Its the image placement you set under floating-image-wrapper. If you are using any css framework, it will also help you better

Comment: B) Alaksander, I use CSS. Is it possible to show the image-floating-wrapper as extra layer centered in the middle of the screen (while the table is under it) where the images are 50% of their original width and height in 2 or more rows of 5 images? I have some categories with 30 images (6x5).

Comment: Yes. You can. Splitting the screen as 5 parts depends on css framework you use or use flex design with width as 20%